# How to use Layout Selector in Orchard?

Tags: layout, themes, orchardcms

In Orchard,I use the Layout Selector Module,I just only see the default option.I have multiple layouts in my active theme.For example,Layout-About.cshtml,Layout-Case.cshtml,Layout-News.cshtml... I don't know why just have one option in layout's list.

Answer (score 0):

Layers are used for `Widgets` only and allow you to specify custom list of widgets for page depending with layer [rules](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets#AddingaLayer). One `Layout.cshtml` is used in this case regardless of the layers.

If you need several `Layout.cshtml` templates in your application you can use `URL Alternates` module, which allow you create templates for specific URLs. Click [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates) for details.